# Automate inputs for unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Rephrasing the question: I want to automate inputs for unit testing in order to secure 100% code coverage.

Is there a way for me myself to do this, or could there perhaps be a 3rd party tool which does it?

Comment: I think you need to rephrase the question to be something like 'I want to automate generating inputs for tests so that all code paths in the method under test are exercised. Whats the best way to do this? If a tool exists which does this already then I'm happy to use that'. Otherwise its a please recommend a tool for me question. And when rephrased you might be more interesting answers as well as finding out about the tool you once stumbled across

Comment: Sam > You're right, I'll do just that :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft labs has such a tool, called [PEX](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/), which I believe was recently released as an extension for visual studio called [code digger](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fb5badda-4ea3-4314-a723-a1975cbdabb4).

I don't know if this is the tool you mean, but it might be an alternative if not.

Comment: That's the one I used back the days - perfect! :-)